# I can't give name to a class on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

When I go to name a class on Eclipse I get this message "Source folder is not a Java project" and I can't press Finish. I am new to Eclipse so sorry if I'm asking a stupid question. I googled it and I couldn't find any solution to my problem. I downloaded java JDK 7 because they told us from our school that we need it. I don't know why I need the JDK, I just downloaded it. Do I have to do anything with the JDK? I found on the internet that I have to do something with the Java Build Path maybe.

Comment: This page will help you... a lot http://www.eclipse.org/resources/?category=Getting%20Started

Comment: Do not downvote a newbie, tell him what he should do better.

Comment: Nikos, how did you create your project?

Comment: Yes tell me what I did wrong cause I am a newbie.
@KevinD I figured it out! I did file->new->projesct instead of java project. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably creating the project with

```
File -> New -> Project
```

Instead use:

```
File -> New -> Java Project
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First, right click on the folder where you have added the class.

`Build path -> use as source folder`

and then create the class